# Foto de directorio activo desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, directorioactivo

Tengo una aplicación C# .Net en donde uso autenticación de windows para el login, lo que necesito es traer la imagen que tiene el usuario en el directorio activo para usarla en mi aplicación.¿Como puedo hacer esto desde C#?.

Comment: Saludos Nico, revisa este enlace por favor: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 te ayudará a interactuar mejor con el sitio :)

Comment: mas alla de obtener la imagen, como estas consultando Active Directory ?

Comment: Me conecto por BD por medio de un SP